# I encountered an error when importing a GLB file using Blender

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

When I use Blender to import GLB files, I will encounter an error message like this“Extension KHR_animation_pointer is not available on this addon version”
When this file is displayed in the front-end, there will be a texture animation. I want to know how this animation is implemented, but I found that Blender cannot import it
[image]

As shown in the above image, this file contains animations of multiple pipeline media flow directions. The animation is the arrow moving in the corresponding direction, but it seems that this is not a model animation, but an animation of the texture on the model. However, Blender does not support the production of texture animation
If it is not possible to achieve this effect in Blender, can you provide some other ways to achieve this effect?